# python twitter crawling(scraping) JSON error

Tags: python, json, twitter, web-scraping, web-crawler

I did.(Pip install json, Pip install simplejson)

However, errors occur.

- simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at:
  line 1 column 65922 (char 65921)
- tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to parse JSON payload: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 65922 (char 65921)

What should I do?

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json
import simplejson

search_term = 'word1'
search_term2= 'word2'
search_term3='word3'

lat = "xxxx"
lon = "xxxx"
radius = "xxxx"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)

API_key = "xxxx"
API_secret = "xxxx"
Access_token = "xxxx"
Access_token_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term, search_term2, search_term3),
                rpp=1000,
                geocode=location,
                include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/workk2.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}   
i = 0       

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text   
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')  
    i += 1


wfile.close()
```

Comment: Unless your python is very old, you don't need to `pip install simplejson` or `pip install json`, json is built-in; and please post the complete traceback (the entire error message).

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I'll go home and turn the program back.
And I'll raise the entire contents of the error.Please wait.(T-T)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid If i'm writing a comment, please answer again.(ToT)